ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric
I am doing a pre-processing for my data before applying sklearn models, but I am having trouble identifying why an error keeps happening. When I run the code for each individual column index in ColumTransformer, it works well for each variable. However, the error happens when I apply it to multiple columns.

What is the problem when I run it all together?
How can you identify which column causes the error using codes? (I checked it by changing the argument manually)
What is the remedy for the error when a single column causes this error?

Data and example code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Number of samples
num_samples = 1000

# Generating random data
data = {
    'Feature_1': np.random.rand(num_samples),
    'Feature_2': np.random.rand(num_samples),
    'Feature_3': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], num_samples),
    'Feature_4': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], num_samples),
    'Feature_5': np.random.choice(['M', 'N', 'O'], num_samples),  # Non-numeric values intentionally introduced
    'Feature_6': np.random.choice(['P', 'Q', 'R'], num_samples),  # Non-numeric values intentionally introduced
    'Feature_7': np.random.choice(['D', 'E', 'F'], num_samples),
    'Feature_8': np.random.choice(['G', 'H', 'I'], num_samples),
    'Feature_9': np.random.choice(['S', 'T', 'U'], num_samples),
    'Feature_10': np.random.rand(num_samples),
    'Feature_11': np.random.rand(num_samples),
    'Feature_12': np.random.choice(['V', 'W', 'X'], num_samples),
    'Feature_13': np.random.choice(['Y', 'Z'], num_samples),
    'Feature_14': np.random.choice(['P', 'Q', 'R'], num_samples),
    'Feature_15': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], num_samples),
    'Target': np.random.choice([0, 1], num_samples)
}


categorical_indices = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15]

d = pd.DataFrame(data)

X = d.values

ct = ColumnTransformer(
            transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), categorical_indices)],
            remainder='passthrough'
                    )
X_1 = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 588, in _hstack
    converted_Xs = [check_array(X,

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 588, in <listcomp>
    converted_Xs = [check_array(X,

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 673, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/25/5mycjlz1013629wcstsb_mwh0000gn/T/ipykernel_24019/2314645552.py", line 10, in <module>
    X_1 = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 529, in fit_transform
    return self._hstack(list(Xs))

  File "/Users/jaeyoungkim/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 593, in _hstack
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.


Where is the definition for ColumnTransformer and OneHotEncoder?

My apologies, @MohamadGhaithAlzin. Please see my edit.

Your categorical_indices are off by 1.
The index starts at 0.
categorical_indices = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15]
categorical_indices = [x - 1 for x in categorical_indices]
# categorical_indices = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14]

